# node.js require modules in virtual machine script

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm creating a commandline interface with node.js that runs an external script

```
> myapp build "path/to/script.js"
```

myapp is a node.js application that executes the script passed as a commandline argument.
To keep things brief, it basically does this:

```
var vm = require("vm");
var fs = require("fs");

var code = fs.readFileSync(scriptPath, { encoding: "utf8" }); // read "path/to/script.js"
var script = vm.createScript(code, scriptPath);
var context = vm.createContext({ require: require });

script.runInNewContext(context);
```

The contents of "path/to/script.js" look something like this:

```
var fs = require("fs"); // this works
var date = require("./date.js"); // supposed to load "path/to/date.js" but fails
```

My problem is that `require()` doesn't work properly in the external script. It works correctly for "native" modules like `fs` but fails on local files, probably because it doesn't know where to look up the modules.

I've considered to simply use following code:

```
require(scriptPath);
```

but then I can't inject my own script context.

I could write my own `require` function that emulates the built-in require but starts looking for modules in `scriptPath` but that seems a bit tedious...

Comment: var myLib=require("./myfile.js");

Comment: @dandavis how is that even remotely helpful...

Comment: i didn't see you were passing require. i didn't know that was even possible. might try { require: require.bind(this) } for context, but you'll likely need to setup process as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used [sandboxed-module](https://github.com/felixge/node-sandboxed-module) to solve a similar problem.

```
var Sandbox = require('./sandboxed-module')
Sandbox.require(scriptPath);
```

`Sandbox.require` loads code from disk and runs it in a new context.  It provides a sandbox-specfiic `require` function that allows you to tweak how `require` works.

Comment: Thanks, I should have thought of searching in NPM myself. I settled for the `require-like` module which sandboxed-module depends on and is closer to what I'm looking for.